# ASP.NET DATAGRID Not moving to next page

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I've got a ASP.NET web page, which has a bound datagrid on it, it was having trouble with showing vertical and horizontal scroll bars when it got over 14 items in it, so I decided to move the datagrid to paging, which works fine when it first loads, it shows the first 14 items, and places the correct number of next page links at the bottom, however when I click on one of these, the page post back to itself BUT stays page one

Any clues at to what I might have missed / need to check

Thanks in advance

Comment: Paging support is dependent on your datasource and method of databinding, can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you handle the page_indexchanging event:

```
Protected Sub gvRequests_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles gvRequests.PageIndexChanging
    Me.gvRequests.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex

    BindGrid()
End Sub
```

You need to handle that event and rebind your grid.

Comment: PS ... Feel very small now :-)